# Add slots using ARM templates

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-deployment-slots

I would like to create same named slots on two different environments. The difference is that on `Integration` I want to have autoswap enabled. I tried doing this using `condition` like below but this does not pass validation because I have two resources with same name.

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('env'), 'Integration')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "staging", <----------------- HERE
      "type": "slots",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('webApiWebSiteName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "autoSwapSlotName": "production"  <----------------- only difference
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "condition": "[equals(parameters('env'), 'Production')]",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "staging", <----------------- HERE
      "type": "slots",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[variables('webApiWebSiteName')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could only created a web app with a name that's unique [across all of Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftweb), because it would generate an endpoint to your website.
[image]

About slots, you could also check the table in the link. They could hold the same name between **different sites( app services)**, but could not hold the same name under **one site**. Not sure about the environment you said, if it means the develop and staging environment, the two slots are still under one app service.

Comment: I'm creating one appservice per environment (with different names on each). And I try to add slot with same name to both of them.